# list comprehension on a dictionary giving empty list

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a dictionary as below :

```
 'give': (('VBP', 6), ('VB', 15)),
 'discounts': ('NNS', 1),
 'maintaining': ('VBG', 4),
 'increasing': ('VBG', 18),
 'spending': (('NN', 24), ('VBG', 2)),
 'become': ((('VBN', 7), ('VB', 15)), ('VBP', 1)),
 'permanent': ('JJ', 2),
 'fixtures': ('NNS', 1),
 'news': ('NN', 24),
 'weeklies': ('NNS', 2),
 'underscore': ('VBP', 1),
 'fierce': ('JJ', 2),
 'competition': ('NN', 10)
```

I am writing a list comprehension as below :

```
result = [x for x in mydict.items() if type(x[1][0]) == 'str']
```

But this results in an empty list, whereas if I see there are many elements in dictionary, for which this condition satisfies.

Comment: The type is never a string but a class.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the expected output? You can use `type(var) is str` for type matching.

Comment: @arsho It's better to use the `isinstance()` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you can change `'str'` to `str` i.e.

```
result = [x for x in mydict.items() if type(x[1][0]) == str]
```

or may be you can try with `isinstance` method to check if it is the instance of `string` ([details](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance)):

```
result = [x for x,value in mydict.items() if isinstance(x[1][0],str)]
print(result)
```

Result:

```
['increasing', 'maintaining', 'fierce', 'permanent', 'fixtures', 'underscore', 'news', 'weeklies', 'discounts', 'become', 'give', 'competition', 'spending']
```